# Scatterv/Gatherv with MPI to return a large vector

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I'm new to MPI, and I've been tasked to use it to calculate a very large matrix of size L*M as part of a larger body of code. We iterate from 0 to L, perform some calculations, and save M values to the result matrix. The results from each iteration over L are independent of one another and its the largest time bottleneck in my code, so parellelizing it seems like a reasonable choice.

The code I am trying to parallelize is, boiled down:

```
//preceding code

int M = 12;
for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) //START OF PARALLEL CHUNK
{
    funkystuffresults = dosomefunkystuff(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        resultmatrix[i*M + j] = funkystuffresults
    }
}//END OF PARALLEL CHUNK
```

Due to the nature of the code that precedes this chunk, I can't be certain of the value of L before runtime and it almost certainly can't be cleanly divided by the number of processes. From my research, it appears to me like MPI_Scatterv is the ideal function to use here.

My initial attempt at using this code:

```
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    int sendcounts[world_size];
    int displs[world_size];
    vector<int> rec_buf(L);
    int rem = L%world_size;
    int counttester = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < world_size; i++)
    {
        sendcounts[i] = L/world_size;
        if (rem > 0)
        {
            sendcounts[i]++;
            rem--;
        }
        displs[i] = counttester;
        counttester += sendcounts[i];
    }
    vector<int> paralleli(L);
    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
    {
        paralleli[i] = i;
    }
    MPI_Scatterv(&paralleli, sendcounts, displs, MPI_INT, &rec_buf, L, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    for (int i = 0; i < sendcounts[world_rank]; i++) //START OF PARALLEL CHUNK
    {
         //previously mentioned code
    }
```

This seems very unwieldy to me for what I would imagine is a pretty common type of problem. To use this code will require a significant amount of modifying the "funky stuff" in my code, so I'm hoping there is a better way to do this. Is it ideal to be using scatterv (and presumably gatherv afterwards)? I'm hoping to use an implementation that also works even if parallelization is not used.

Comment: As a side note, do you find anything in MPI to be 'wieldy'? MPI is well defined, it works, but most libraries are based on C-style api, so 'unwieldiness' is a common thing and the first thing I usually do is to wrap and hide as much MPI settings and calls as I can.. (not that I did it many times.. ten maybe.. and that was a time ago). Since that's a common thing, I'd search for some C++ wrappers. After all these years and after lambdas/etc were finally introduced, making a type-safe lambda-based set of wrappers should be quite simple and I'd expect that someone already did it.

Comment: I've seen a number of examples of MPI used (mostly with bcast and reduce rather than scatter and gather) that, on the surface, look pretty simple. I'm brand new to MPI though so I admittedly don't have much experience with what to expect.

Comment: Just FYI: it seems people are actually working on something https://github.com/patflick/mxx or https://blogs.cisco.com/performance/new-life-for-cxx-in-mpi - but consider it a side note, not answer. I actually doubt you could use them if your assignement/task was "use MPI". And also the former looks actually a bit more complex than what you have now so, d'oh.

Comment: I am not sure you can `MPI_Scatterv(&paralleli, ..., &rec_buf, ...)`. `MPI_Scatterv(&paralleli[0], ..., &rec_buf[0], ...)` will definitely work. I am not fluent in C++, but based on previous answers, `MPI_Scatterv(paralleli,data(), ..., rec_buf.data(), ...)` might do the trick too.

Comment: as a side note, you can allocate a smaller `rec_buf`. Max size is `rem + 1` (`L` is needlessly larger here)

Comment: Thank you @GillesGouaillardet. My problem with Scatterv seems to be fixed.